# Deploy containerize project using Jenkins and Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, jenkins, containers, continuous-integration

I have project running using several docker containers. Now I want to automate deployment using Jenkins (push triggers). I have three scenarios but I like none of them. here are these three different scenarios:

1) I deploy changes on server, then on server I run `docker-compose build`, to recreate potentially changed images and then run containers.

**downside** - I don't build these new images on my host, but just on the server, so I can't be sure that build will occur successfully, It may be buggy and cause several errors without first checking.

2) I can first check that project builds successfully but first running `docker-compose build` on my Jenkins server and deploying after that.

**downside** - I run `docker-compose build` two times. on my Jenkins server and on the production server.

3) I can build on my Jenkins server, then push it on docker hub and pull on server. so I build only once.

**downside** - as I said I have several images. so in this scenario I have to upload maybe 6 images on the docker hub and then pull them on server.

As I said I don't want to use any of these because of their downsides. So maybe there are other better way of doing things like that?

Comment: Hi! This is a really interesting question and there isn't one good answer. We could have a lengthy discussion on this.  Many people face the same challenges.  Unfortunately, this isn't a good place to have that discussion, see the guidelines here https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask.  Have you found a Slack channel where you can discuss?  If you have a specific problem using either Docker or Jenkins maybe you can repost this question.

Comment: https://www.networktocode.com/community/ would be the place I'd start in Slack-land.  It might also be on-topic at https://devops.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: 3 should be the winner so you have an archive of your artifacts.  Your downside there seems relatively thin and vague to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually good practice to split out your build and deploy steps to separate jobs.  This way you build/test once and can migrate the versioned image across your environments when ready.  You can also trigger the build to occur whenever the code changes, creating unique image version#'s when needed.

Your deploy job should contain an option to specify the docker image version to deploy which also helps with rollback.   Option #3 IMO is the best one.

If you don't want to bother with dockerhub, you can easily create a local docker registry that you can push to as well to keep your images.  See [docker_registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry)